# Astonishing Analogies

Tags: word-property, explanation

An analogy can compare a comparison.

What is the answer to the following question?

### Alarm is to Bread as Course is to Dot - Explain

Comment: When I started, I thought this makes no sense, but then, I took another glance and  I thought that was bolded weirdly, and then I noticed the answer

Comment: I'm not sure that I see a question in the last line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The bolded letters turn out to be abcde.

Answer (score 1):

Alarm is to Bread.

> Anagram of *alarmbread*: **BLAME RADAR**. The alarm compares to the radar beeping (alarms can beep as well) as it picks up a signal (namely the bread). Bread, however, is not something to be detected by a radar.

Course is to Dot.

> Anagram of *coursedot*: **OUTSCORED**. The course is the trajectory of the dot (namely the ball) in some field and ball game (cricket, baseball, etc).

Word property:

> **OFF**. When you get outscored, you have "defeated (an opponent) by focusing on the **off**ense". And now, the bread is **off** the radar.

Also,

> Taking the capital letters of the words make **ABCDE**, to which the next letter is **F**.

Comment: nice! I didn't see that, but +1.

Comment: @Alto thank you for the upvote! I am now on exactly $3000$ rep, yay! I don't really care much about rep, but $3000$ seems like an accomplished number :D

Comment: wow, thanks. i'm out of ideas for a puzzle, though